# How to get element's mouseMove position?

Tags: java, arrays, json, mouseevent, vaadin

I currently have some code written to retrieve the X and Y coordinates whenever the mouse moves over the canvas element, but right now the coordinates aren't updating and only printing the same coordinates again and again. How should I achieve this using my existing code?

Canvas.java:

```
public Canvas(int width, int height) {

element = getElement();
element.addEventListener("mousemove", event -> {

        JsonObject mousePos = event.getEventData();

        double mouseX = mousePos.getNumber("event.x");
        double mouseY = mousePos.getNumber("event.y");

        MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
        mousePosArray.add(currentPos);
        System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(0));

 }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add currentPos to the Array but then you print only the first element of the array

```
System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(0));
```

get(0) get the first mouse position you add to your array.

You can use this to print the last mouse position:

```
System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(mousePosArray.count -1));
```